# "logical root block and symbol is not supported in target" error in ISE Design Suite 14.7

Tags: fpga, xilinx, spartan

I'm a total noob in ISE Design Suite 14.7 and I don't know a thing.
I'm trying to make a SR latch (I know there is a SR latch in ISE but I want to create it myself to practice).
the SR latch itself works fine but I get an error from Top_Module.
here is the code for SR latch:

[image]

and the top module code and the error when I want to implement it:

[image]

It works fine when I change the top module to SRlatch.v and not the topmodule.v.
what should I do?
please don't say I have to search on google because I don't understand a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. What I wrote was rudimentary and also wasn't well connected and it couldn't implement it.
But I wanted to see the result by using ModelSim and it was fine with it and compiled it.